# `Redirect 301` will redirect a subpage to url, but not an ip to url

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

Im trying to rediect my static ip to my url. To do this ive tried using the following line in my .htaccess file :

```
Redirect 301 101.101.101.101 http://example.com/
```

But `101.101.101.101` dosnt rediect.

I use the same pattern as below to rediect sub pages, which does work

```
Redirect 301 /somepage.html http://example.com/
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not redirect ip using mod-alias, use mod-rewrite instead

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^101\.101\.101\.101$
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com [L,R,NE]
```